# Why does .prop('src') return wrong value when property src is null or empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9d8e4wh/)

```js
$('img').click(function () {
  alert($(this).prop('src'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" />
<img src="" style="width: 10px; height: 10px; border: 1px solid;">
```

When I click the second image, it alerts `http://stacksnippets.net/js`.

Why?

Comment: Why did you remove my edit? I provided you with a working jsfiddle and made the invisible and unclickable image visible and clickable.

Comment: @Oleander Because I don't want everyone must redirect to another page to check my example. It's already on the page.

Comment: Everyone here at SO is using jsfiddle to provide running examples. Your current code also doesn't work here. Click on the image and try it your self, no alert message is given.

Comment: @Oleander Are you sure? Have you tried it? Just clicking and it alerts `http://fiddle.jshell.net/g9d8e4wh/show/`

Comment: @Oleander that's because the Stack Snippets feature doesn't allow `alert`; otherwise, the code runs fine. Still worth noting to the OP, of course.

Comment: @apsillers Which is why I added a working code example :)

Comment: @Mr.Wolf I've only tried pressing the "run" button here on SO, and that doesn't work.

Comment: @Oleander Yah. Can you give me an answer for my question?

Comment: @Mr.Wolf You got 4 answers below, aren't they enough?

Comment: @Oleander All of answers say: Don't use `.prop()` for `src`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official doc :

> HTMLImageElement.src
>       Is a DOMString that reflects the src HTML attribute, containing the full URL of the image including base URI.

which obviously means that, without any path given into `src`, the `src` attribute will only be equal to the `base URI`

link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

a quick javascript workaround would be to set `src` to `null` if it's value is empty

```
var src = $(this).prop('src') || null;
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/g9d8e4wh/1/

concerning your `.attr() vs .prop()` concern, I suggest you to head on there 
[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: `$(this).attr('src') || null` is shorter.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't mention about `.attr('src')`. You can edit your demo, replace `attr` by `prop`. It will alert `http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/`

Comment: So, why `attr`, why `prop`? I wanna use `.prop` because it's faster than `.attr()`

Comment: @Mr.Wolf edited answer based on your comment
(@)Oriol idd

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm :)

Answer (score 1):

When SRC is empty, $(this) retuns the IMG object and src returns the objects context and baseURI.  You can see it by viewing the object properties in the console:

```
$('img').click(function () {
    alert($(this).prop('src'))
    console.log($(this));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because [`src`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-img-src) is reflected:

> The `alt`, `src` IDL attributes must [reflect](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#reflect) the respective content attributes of the same name.

And when getting a reflecting IDL attribute which has an URL value, you get the absolute one:

> If a reflecting IDL attribute is a `DOMString` attribute whose content
>   attribute is defined to contain a URL, then on getting, the IDL
>   attribute must [resolve](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#resolve-a-url) the value of the content attribute relative to
>   the element and return the resulting [absolute URL](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#absolute-url) if that was
>   successful, or the empty string otherwise

If you don't want this behavior, you can use `getAttribute` to get the content attribute instead of the IDL one.

Comment: Small question: Why is `src` called `attribute` in your first quote? I think it's `src` property

Comment: @Mr.Wolf [IDL attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#idl-attributes) are also commonly called [properties](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.26). The official names are different because one is defined by Web IDL and the other by ECMAScript.

Comment: Sorry for many questions, but all of your links don't mention about how to use `.prop()` to check a `src` is null or not. Like this: `if ($('img').prop('src') == null || $('img').prop('src') == '') {}`

Comment: jQuery's `prop` returns the IDL attribute (property). jQuery's `attr` returns the content attribute. The former will be the resolved absolute URL, the latter the value you used in the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a synchronization between properties and attributes but not for all cases. For example 'href' and 'src' are not synchronized. In your case you need to use

```
$('img').click(function () {
  alert($(this).attr('src'))
})
```

or `getAttribute()` when using vanilla JS. You can learn more here - > http://javascript.info/tutorial/attributes-and-custom-properties